# Why is my Question Considered a Duplicate and Closed?

Tags: discussion, support, duplicate-question

I would appreciate some clarification on why my question - [Why is “scaling”, for raster images, recommended to design large Images?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/38963/why-is-scaling-for-raster-images-recommended-to-design-large-images) - is still being considered a duplicate of [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/26354/8708).

---

Since posting here, I have edited and refined my question more. Moreover, it is really irritating that there are some good answers in the comments. If the question wasn't tagged a duplicate and closed, these could have been the answers and be a useful resource for many.

Answer (score 1):

Even looking at your original it seems slightly different but this is community driven so others may not have taken it that way. To be fair though while I don't see it as a duplicate I do see it as *barely* a design question.

In any case, your question was reopened now, so maybe it was just taking some time to get approved. We're not all on over the weekend.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue I had was your choice of wording. Either I read it wrong or the wording was not at all clear regarding what you were asking. I was looking forward to you editing and rewording as DA01 suggested. But I guess, that wasn't really a priority.